# How do I get the output from my VBScript Console using C#?

Tags: c#, vbscript

My application opens a website then runs a VBS file to do some data input. Once it's completed the data input, I want to quit the application.

In my current iteration, the VBS file executes and my C# code keeps going (quitting the web app before the data entry is completed).

```c
Process.Start(appPath + @"external\website.url");
getAllProcesses(false);

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(appPath + @"\external\UNLOCK.vbs", employeeID);

Process scriptProc = new Process();
scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cscript";
scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = appPath + @"external\";            
scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "UNLOCK.vbs " + employeeID;
scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //prevent console window from popping up
scriptProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
scriptProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
scriptProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
scriptProc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
scriptProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
scriptProc.Start();

scriptProc.WaitForExit(); // <-- Optional if you want program running until your script exit

Read(scriptProc.StandardOutput);
Read(scriptProc.StandardError);

while(true)
{
    String completed = Console.ReadLine();
    scriptProc.StandardInput.WriteLine(completed);
    if(completed.CompareTo("Completed") == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (scriptProc.HasExited)
{
    getAllProcesses(true);
    Application.Exit();
}
scriptProc.Close();
```

I want to only execute

```c
getAllProcesses(true);
Application.Exit();
```

ONLY After I get output from my VBS file that says "Completed".

My VBS file has a line that says

```vbs
WScript.Echo "Completed"
```

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```c
Process scriptProc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.WorkingDirectory = appPath + @"external\";
info.FileName = "Cscript.exe";
info.Arguments = "UNLOCK.vbs" + employeeID;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
scriptProc.StartInfo = info;
scriptProc.Start();
scriptProc.WaitForExit();
bool exit = false;

while (!scriptProc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    if (scriptProc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() == "Completed")
    {
        exit = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (exit == true)
{
    getAllProcesses(true);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Suggest amending your answer to indicate the changes that you recommend me made to make it easier to read and understand the answer