# Programmatically get the full path of a shared folder on another computer?

Tags: c#, networking, unc, network-drive, mapped-drive

I know that you can get the path to a mapped drive (e.g. [Find UNC path of a network drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive)), but what if the only thing I have is just the path to the shared folder?

For example, let's say I have a friend who is sharing the folder `C:\MyDocs\PublicDoc` over the network. I can access it under the path `\\danas-pc\PublicDoc`. Is there any way that I could, being on another computer, determine that `\\danas-pc\PublicDoc` actually maps to `\\danas-pc\c$\MyDocs\PublicDoc`?

I ask because I am given a path to a log file that has the  path (e.g. `\danas-pc\c$\MyDocs\PublicDoc\mylog.log` )and I need to check if it matches the same path that is set in another location. The other location has the "short path" (e.g. `\\danas-pc\PublicDoc\mylog.log` ), and thus, even though the log paths lead to the same location, the program determines that they are different. I wanted to see if there's a way to figure out that they are pointing to the same location.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I suppose that should give you an answer? https://superuser.com/questions/1146811/getting-real-path-of-file-on-samba-server-from-client

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Or maybe you don't. There are any number of UNC paths that can refer to the same file on a server, including one that goes through the pre-defined `<drive-letter>$` share name. What makes any of those _the_ "real" path? What if someone's configured their server to disable the `<drive-letter$>` share? Please fix your question so it's clear what you actually expect to happen in all cases and why. It's unlikely you can accomplish your goal, but at the moment, it's not clear what that goal actually is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hi Peter, thank you for your insightful reply, I did not realize that the user can disable the shares or that there can be many UNC Paths. I ask because I am given a path to a log file that has the <drive-letter$> path and I need to check if it matches the same path that is set in another location. The other location has the "short path", and thus, even though the log paths lead to the same things, the program determines that they are different, I wanted to see if there's a way to figure out that they are pointing to the same location.

Comment: @DanielMann I updated my question to give the reason :)

Answer (score 5):

I can't imagine why you might need this since for the remote instance's full path is \danas-pc\PublicDoc but if you let your imagination thrive I'd suggest something like this:

(1) on the remote computer inside the share folder you can drop a small script that if executed return the full path. You have to search for appropriate coding for windows or linux environment also you need to have execution privilege or rights on it. for example on windows you can have a vbscrit or cscript and a .sh script in linux.

Also please note that seeing it from the remote host, in terms of the remote host the full path is \NAME-OR-IP\Path\to\Folder\or\File etc. For you on the remote connection that is the full path ;)

---

UPDATE:
as per the comment below, this is a full script that does the following

1. creates a vbscript with code in it to retrieve the current full path
2. copies the files into the network desired path
3. executes the vbscript and reads the result back
4. deletes the vbscript

Assuming: you have the read/write access on the network folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetNetworkFullPath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var networkFolder = "\\\\REMOTE-PC-NAME\\SharedFolder";
            var nameOfVBScript = "capturepath.vbs";
            var vbsOutput = "";

            //Get the name of the current directory
            var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Console.WriteLine("Current Dir: " + currentDirectory);


            //1. CREATE A VBSCRIPT TO OUTPUT THE PATH WHERE IT IS PRESENT
            //Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129327/how-to-get-the-fully-qualified-path-for-a-file-in-vbscript
            var vbscriptToExecute = "Dim folderName \n" +
                                        "folderName = \"\" \n" +
                                        "Dim fso \n" +
                                        "Set fso = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\") \n" +
                                        "Dim fullpath \n" +
                                        "fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(folderName) \n" +
                                        "WScript.Echo fullpath \n";


            //Write that script into a file into the current directory
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@""+ nameOfVBScript  + "", vbscriptToExecute);


            //2. COPY THE CREATED SCRIPT INTO THE NETWORK PATH
            //Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, nameOfVBScript);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(networkFolder, nameOfVBScript);

            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            //3. EXECUTE THAT SCRIPT AND READ THE OUTPUT
            //Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050195/how-do-i-get-the-output-from-my-vbscript-console-using-c
            Process scriptProc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.WorkingDirectory = @"" + networkFolder + "";
            info.FileName = "Cscript.exe";
            info.Arguments = nameOfVBScript;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            scriptProc.StartInfo = info;
            scriptProc.Start();
            scriptProc.WaitForExit();
            bool exit = false;

            while (!scriptProc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                vbsOutput = scriptProc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("vbscript says: " + vbsOutput);


            //4. DELETE THE FILE YOU JUST COPIED THERE
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"" + networkFolder + "\\" + nameOfVBScript);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when executed remotely the script replies with the Network Path :( so disappointed...really sorry! As long as execution is happening from a user outside the remote system it will reply with the absolute path related to that instance. I think an internal process/user should execute the file and reply back with the answer to the application.

[image]

I'll try to think something more tomorrow and maybe reply back if I'm lucky.

Comment: Can you show a small example of C# code that would write this file in the path, execute the file, capture the output, and delete the file? The idea is good, but it would make the answer much more complete.

Comment: hi Rufus, I did the script as per your comment but unfortunately it didn't work with remote execution. I believe every time the execution is happening remotely the path is considered as such. An internal process on the host machine should execute the script and send the result back to the main application for us to read